# Get minutes from two timestamps, which are on a Sunday in PHP

Tags: php

I have two timestamps, which possibly can be any date and time. I want to get all minutes, which were on Sunday.
For a better understanding: The start and and end timestamp represent a date and time where an employee starts his work and finish his work. I want to get the minutes in sum, which the employee worked on a Sunday.

Here is my code:

```
function get_sunday_hours_from_timestamps($startTimestamp, $endTimestamp) {
    $start = new DateTime();
    $start->setTimestamp($startTimestamp);
    $end = new DateTime();
    $end->setTimestamp($endTimestamp);
    $workedMinutes = 0;
    $current = clone $start;
    while ($current <= $end) {
        $next = clone $current;
        $next->modify('next day');
        if ($current->format('w') == 0) {
            $dayStart = ($current < $start) ? $start : $current;
            $dayEnd = ($next > $end) ? $end : $next;
            $diff = $dayEnd->diff($dayStart);
            $minutes = $diff->days * 1440 + $diff->h * 60 + $diff->i;
            $workedMinutes += $minutes;
        }
        $current = $next;
    }

    return $workedMinutes / 60;
    // return $workedMinutes;
}
```

Comment: You say: _"I have two timestamps, which possibly can be any date and time"_. So the start can come after the end? An employee could work continuous for weeks? Or is your initial statement not true? Does the start always come before the end, and an employee has a clear maximum work time which is always less than 1 day?

Comment: Wont you first have to work out if the date in the timestamps is actually a Sunday, or if these dates include a Sunday? I think your Spec has started somewhere in the middle of a process. You may need to fill in the beginning and the end for it to make full sense

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your input. I was able to solve the problem. Hope this helps anybody else.

```
 function get_sunday_hours_from_timestamps($startTimestamp, $endTimestamp) {
    $totalMinutes = 0;


    $startDay = strtotime("midnight", $startTimestamp);
    $endDay = strtotime("tomorrow", $endTimestamp) - 1;


    for ($currentDay = $startDay; $currentDay <= $endDay; $currentDay = strtotime("+1 day", $currentDay)) {
        if (date("l", $currentDay) == "Sunday") {

        $start = max($startTimestamp, $currentDay);
        $end = min($endTimestamp, strtotime("tomorrow", $currentDay) - 1);


        $totalMinutes += ($end - $start) / 60;
        }
    }


    return round($totalMinutes / 15) * 0.25;
}
```

Comment: @RiggsFolly this is the answer, not additional information to the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning**: The solution below is highly inefficient and extremely slow, especially for large time periods as input. It only serves to illustrate a naive approach in an easily readable form. You can use this as a starting point, but use it wisely!

---

A very naive approach to your problem (count sunday minutes in a given time period) could be: Iterate over every minute in you period, check if that minute is on a sunday and count those minutes.

In PHP that could look like this:

```php
function isSunday(DateTimeInterface $dateTime) {
    return $dateTime->format('w') == 0;
}

function countSundayMinutes(DateTime $start, DateTime $end): int
{
    if ($start >= $end) {
        throw new LogicException('end must be > start!');
    }
    $sundayMinutes = 0;
    $current = clone $start;
    while ($current < $end) {
        if (isSunday($current)) {
            $sundayMinutes++;
        }
        $current = $current->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 minute'));
    }

    return $sundayMinutes;
}

echo countSundayMinutes(new DateTime('2023-01-02 00:00'), new DateTime('2023-01-03 00:00')), PHP_EOL; // 0: total 24h, not on sunday
echo countSundayMinutes(new DateTime('2023-01-01 12:00'), new DateTime('2023-01-01 13:00')), PHP_EOL; // 60: total 60 minutes, thereof 60 on sunday
echo countSundayMinutes(new DateTime('2022-12-31 23:00'), new DateTime('2023-01-01 01:00')), PHP_EOL; // 60: total 12 minutes, thereof 60 on sunday
echo countSundayMinutes(new DateTime('2022-12-31 00:00'), new DateTime('2023-01-03 00:00')), PHP_EOL; // 1440: total 72h, thereof 24h (1440 minutes) on sunday
```

But i'm sure you'll be able to add many optimizations to that algorithm, e.g. you could check first if the given period includes any sundays at all...